# Compare Date in Condition [Vega-Lite]

Tags: datetime, colors, observable, conditional-formatting, vega-lite

I'm super new to this and trying out Observable and Vega-Lite for the first time. The following code works when the datum is a quantitative string but not when it's a date.

```
vl.color({"condition":{"test":"datum['dateAnnounced']<'2020-03-15'","value":"black"}, "value":"red"})
```

Can someone show me the correct way to compare Date fields, please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`condition.test` accepts [Predictate](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/predicate.html). It has string format which you're using, but also it could be an object like this:

```json
condition: {
  test: {
    field: 'dateAnnounced', // your date field
    lt: { year: 2020, month: 3, date: 15 } // 'less than' a date in Vega DateTime format
  }
}
```

They call this object "field predicate". It has `field` prop and a comparison operator `lt` or `gt` or `equal`, etc.
There are some examples from [Field Predicate section](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/predicate.html#field-predicate) of the doc:

```json
{"field": "car_color", "equal": "red"} // car_color === red

{"field": "height", "lt": 180} // height < 180

{"field": "date", // 2006-01-01 < date && date < 2008-02-20
  "range": [
    {"year": 2006, "month": "jan", "date": 1},
    {"year": 2008, "month": "feb", "date": 20}
  ]
}
```